# How to delete all duplicate image just keep the first one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
product_images

id - product_id - image - main_image - date
```

image:

[image]

This table contains the whole image of my products.

What I need a query in SQL to remove all duplicate `product_id` and keep the very first one which is in the image above that contains an image `2019/03/9g.jpg`

Comment: mysql or postgres?

Comment: @poongilbert mysql

Comment: All the images here for 11544 are duplicates?

Comment: @zip no there are many product_id just did this to show the duplication of the images

Comment: Great, that's what I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use where not exists for this:

This below gives the list to delete

```
select *
from product_image a
where exists
(
select 1 from product_image b 
where a.product_id = b.product_id and a.id < b.id
)
```

This below delete all but the first for each product_id

```
    Delete From product_images 
    where id not in
    ( 
    select id from
    (
      select id 
      from product_images a
      where not exists
      (
         select 1 from product_images b 
         where a.product_id = b.product_id and a.id > b.id
      )
    )a
   )
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c048b/10)

Comment: means the second one?

Comment: Yes, the second one deletes the rows, the first shows you the rows that will be deleted

Comment: what is ( a , b ) mean?

Comment: a and b a aliases given to product_image so i wont repeat the names. You could call them pi1 (product_image 1) and pi2 (product_image 2) instead of a and b.

Comment: I got this error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I removed the alias, this will be good now. Sorry for the reworks

Comment: new one! ; #1093 - You can't specify target table 'product_images' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Ok, I have wrapper the inner reference in a derived table. Let me know

Comment: That removes the whole duplicate images without keeping the first one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209532/discussion-between-zip-and-musa).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. The images being deleted are those not in `min(id)` from `product_images` grouped by `product_id`.

Images are duplicates if they have the same `product_id` but no the same `id`, we only want to keep the minimal-id member of all the images grouped by `product_id`.

```
DELETE FROM product_images
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT min(id)
                 FROM product_images
                 GROUP BY product_id);
```